# AWS Athena - is there a way to cause Athena to not update query result for reuse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

So I am using Athena with Java, and use query reuse for 12 hours. However sometimes we get new data in the Athena and we would like a mechanism that forces the query to not use saved result but use the new data and store that instead.

Almost like refresh, and notify Athena for the next query dont use old result but query for updated data and store that and use that from now on.

But the tricky point is the query is the same, the data changes. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Athena will only match verbatim SQL for result reuse.

If you know that the underlying data has changed, you can add a unique sequence of symbols (say, the change timestamp) in a comment to your query and keep it till the next data source modification.

Comment: One might consider that there is a metadata column that shows the timestamp for the last update for any given row that could be used for the aforementioned approach: $file_modified_time.  See the following reference for metadata columns: https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#metadata-columns